# Print ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: asp.net

I have a Web form, which just needs to be filled out and printed. Can anyone help me with the Print button coding, please?

Answer (score 6):

A client-side button should do the trick:

```
<input type="button" value="Print Form" onclick="window.print()" />
```

Comment: also take a look at the CSS media type "print", this will let you style your page for the printed view (i.e., hide the menu, underline anchors, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A [quick search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&site=&q=javascript+print&btnG=Search) finds that there is a simple way to do this: `window.print()`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a clientside print button.

Something like:

```
<button onclick="window.print();">Print!</button>
```

This will do much the same as a user clicking file print on their browser.