# Print receipt button in razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, printing

I'm new to Razor. I have my web pages complete but I'm at the point where I want to add a print button to my form.

I see where I can add a print button with Asp.Net [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/330502/Asp-net-Print-the-page-on-image-button-click) but I cannot find where I add it with Razor using MVC.

If there is a thread on this, point me in the right direction, but I didn't find one.

Am I to add a css and use javascript?

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The code is in javascript. If you want to go that way the same code applies to razor

Answer (score 3):

I used this answer:

[Print ASP.NET Web Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184852/print-asp-net-web-form/3184862#3184862)

```
<input type="button" value="Print Form" onclick="window.print()" />
```

And it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any javascript event to any html-helper. For example to add Html-Attribute to Link.

```
@Html.ActionLink(
"print window", 
"Print", 
new { id = "someId" }, 
new { onclick = "window.print();" })
```